# How do i create a MySQL Query for 'People you may know' (friends of friends)?

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
members(id, name, surname, username, password)
friends(uid, friend_uid, confirmed_uid, confirmed_friend_uid)
```

in the friends table the `uid` and `friend_uid` relate to `members.id`, where `uid` is always lower then `friend_uid`. `friends.confirmed` is true when `friends.uid` has agreed to be friends and `friends.friend_confirmed` is true when `friends.friend_uid` has confirmed the friendship.

User A is only friends with B and C, they have both confirmed the friendship. I want a query that will show A a list of B and C's (all A's confirmed friends) confirmed friends that are not already friends with A. Making sure that that if B and C have common friends they are top of the list.

As my MySQL is very rusty I am currently doing this with multiple queries, but this must be very inefficient and I need to create a query to it all for me before it starts effecting the performance of my web site.

I have started reading MySQL documentation and I will update this if I get anywhere, but if someone can help me speed up the process, I will greatly appreciate it.

Here is how i am doing it with a bit pseudo code:

```
member_id_for_A = 1;
friends_of_A = mysql_query("
            SELECT m.*, f.* FROM friends f 
            inner join members m on m.id = f.uid 
              WHERE f.friend_uid = " + member_id_for_A + " AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1 
            UNION
              SELECT m.*, f.* FROM friends f 
              inner join members m on m.id = f.friend_uid 
                WHERE f.uid = " + member_id_for_A + " AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1");

foreach(row : friends_of_A)
{
  friend_id = get_friened_id(row, member_id_for_A);
  friends_of_friend = get_friends(friend_id); // Performs a query like above friends_of_friend
  result = remove_matches(friends_of_A, friends_of_friend); // Remove common friends

  // Do something with results and move onto the next friend
}
```

I know this is very bad code and not efficient, but it was a quick hacky way I could get the functionality I needed until I had the time to learn more MySQL. Hopefully it gives a clear picture of what I am aiming for with one single query.

Comment: Post your queries, so it may be easier for us, too.

Comment: This would be far easier if you defined the table fried with just the fields uid and friend_uid (and posssibly confirmed), and then stored a mutually confirmed friendship as two rows in that table.

Comment: It is my understanding that doing it that way makes the database inefficient. Having two rows for each relationship, just duplicates data.

Comment: you have never told about friend_uid=8 but you have used it in your answer ? This is improper question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look at the [subquery documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) I have managed to come up with a working solution.

In this example A has a `members.id=8`.

```
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE id IN ( 
 SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.uid 
 WHERE f.friend_uid IN ( 
  SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.uid 
  WHERE f.friend_uid=8 AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1  
   UNION SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.friend_uid 
   WHERE f.uid=8 AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1
 ) AND m.id<>8 AND f.confirmed_uid=1 AND f.confirmed_friend_uid=1 
  UNION SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.uid 
  WHERE f.uid IN ( 
   SELECT m.id FROM friends f INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.uid 
   WHERE f.friend_uid=8 AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1 
    UNION SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.friend_uid
    WHERE f.uid=8 AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1
   ) AND m.id<>8 AND f.confirmed_uid=1 AND f.confirmed_friend_uid=1
) AND id NOT IN (
 SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.uid 
 WHERE f.friend_uid=8 AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1  
  UNION SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.friend_uid 
  WHERE f.uid=8 AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1
);
```

This query runs nice and fast and returns friends of all A's friends, that are not already friends of A. It also ensure that friendships have been confirmed by both members in the relationship.

There may well be a way to reduce the size of this query, as the same [subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) is used on three separate occasions in the query as a whole.

```
 SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.uid 
 WHERE f.friend_uid=8 AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1  
  UNION SELECT m.id FROM friends f  INNER JOIN members m on m.id=f.friend_uid 
  WHERE f.uid=8 AND confirmed_uid=1 AND confirmed_friend_uid=1
```

If there is a way to only run this subquery once, please let me know. Otherwise I will edit the answer if/when I figure it out myself.

Comment: subquery will yield you low performance; Joins are very efficient;

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

```
select m.id,m.surname,m.name from friends f1
inner join friends f2
on f1.friend_uid=f2.uid      /* Identify friend of friend*/
inner join members m
on m.id=f2.friend_uid       /* Match & get Friend of Friend's User detail */
where f1.confirmed_uid=1         /* Friend1 is confirmed */
and f2.confirmed_friend_uid=1
and m.id <> f2.uid          /* Friend2 is not already a friend */
```

In Select List, choose your required fields

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that's not quite what I'm looking for. That query does not take into account only want to see friends from A's friends or the that we only want cases where 'friends.confirmed=1' and 'friends.friend_confirmed=1'.

Comment: i have added one more filter as per your case where 'friends.confirmed=1' and 'friends.friend_confirmed=1';
Please check my query again

Comment: This query still does not take the original user into account. Say user A has a `m.id=8` and we want a result set of all user A's friends, confirmed friends, that are not already friends of A.

Comment: what do you mean by m.id =8 ? 
Dont give down vote when your question is not clear! People wont answer your question if you do like that! Kindly revoke down vote.